# Estimating CVaR for non-Gaussian distributions

Tags: cvar

Calculating CVaR needs Gaussian distribution, however, what if the distribution is not Gaussian? Or the distribution is unknown? Can I use many Dirac Delta functions to estimate a distribution and  estimate the CVaR？

Comment: It does not need Gaussian unless you have some analytical formula in mind

Comment: The whole point of CVaR is that is gives more information thanVaR for non-Gaussian distributions. If we presumed distributions are Gaussian, VaR and CVaR would be equivalent since one would imply the other.

Comment: @Magicisinthechain, I am using 55 Dirac Delta functions to estimate a distribution and directly use this estimated distribution to calculate the CVaR, does it feasible or right to do so?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details, you mean calculate quantiles and then average them? CVaR is average of quantiles, so doable but the number of quantiles you need to use to achieve some desired accuracy will depend on the distribution.

Comment: @Magicisinthechain yes, right

Comment: Should work but just like any numerical approximation of integral, the spacing and weights are the key!

Comment: @Magicisinthechain I will try and consider other density estimation methods as Mr Kurtosis in the following answer.

Comment: Ok and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bunch of Dirac delta functions would not be a good idea; you essentially would be assuming a distribution of point masses instead of a continuous distribution. If you work with the integral of that, the empirical CDF, you can get some answers though they may be crude or be very uncertain.

You would do better using a kernel density estimate, an Edgeworth or Cornish-Fisher expansion, or extreme value theory -- though the empirical distribution may sometimes be more conservative.

We prefer these methods for many reasons. Risk is largely driven by the tail behavior of the loss distribution. The empirical CDF alone is unlikely to offer us insight into tail behavior. These methods also infer a smoother distribution. This is crucial for looking at tighter risk measures (say 0.1%-CVaR instead of 5%-CVaR) since tighter risk bounds require more data -- and even more data if you want to reduce the uncertainty of the estimate. We also need smooth distributions to properly compute functions of the loss density. Ultimately, we need more than the empirical CDF for any possible insight into tail behavior, how CVaR changes with the quantile bound, functions of the loss density, or estimates of max loss over some time period.

I also would recommend using *more than one* of these methods since each will give you slightly different answers. That may offer insight into a better estimate of risk or possible weaknesses of one particular approach. For example, if four methods give you a 5%-CVaR of -6% and one method says 5%-CVaR is -1%... maybe check into that one method's assumptions.

Finally: *none* of these methods assume a Gaussian distribution to the data -- nor does anything about computing CVaR. In fact, CVaR would not be useful if the data distribution were Gaussian because then VaR would imply CVaR (and thus be sufficient for capturing risk).

You might benefit from reading the theory and examples in Chapter 8 of *A Quantitative Primer on Investments with $R$*. That has plenty of references to follow up with for each of these methods.

Comment: Thanks, I am using 55 Dirac Delta functions to estimate a distribution with any shape by using deep learning. I am confused why it cannot be a good idea to do so?

Comment: Risk is largely about tail behavior. Dirac deltas have no tails and so any coherent risk measure (like CVaR) you estimate will be off -- and probably very off. You could use 300 or 1000 deltas and still be asking for trouble. Statisticians do not estimate distributions in that way for theory or applications -- and for good reason.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Dirac deltas to estimate quantiles and hope I can use it to estimate a distribution with any shapes. Is that feasible?

Comment: Another question is, there is no assumption of calculating CVaR only for Gaussian distributions right?

Comment: After thinking for a while, my friend, I think I am using Dirac deltas to estimate an empirical distribution function and use the estimated function to calculate CVaR.

Comment: Not feasible. Check out kernel density estimators; that's much closer to what you want, especially since every observation is random and thus a point mass does not make sense. Also, CVaR does not depend on anything being Gaussian. If things were Gaussian, CVaR would be pointless. So you could say it assumes non-Gaussianity.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, since I am using deep learning with many data, and I want to estimate a distribution to do some prediction

Comment: Dear sir, my previous idea was: using the deep learning network to estimate many Dirac deltas working as estimations distribution. Just like estimating empirical distribution

Comment: Dear sir, sorry to bother again. What about this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/73626/132651

Comment: Yep, the integral of those deltas gets you the empirical CDF. That is the crudest estimator available -- and not a good estimate of the density. You would have to not believe anything, not even anything mildly reasonable, to prefer that approach.

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you for your kind and patient answer, could you please summarize your replies to the answer you posted above? I will accept your answer. Your reply is right, statistically, using Dirac deltas is not that great and feasible, but if it has practical good results, I will use it. I think there is a computational trade-off between theoretically good and practically good methods, do you think so?

Comment: Summarized and incorporated into the main answer. I think risk is one area where we know so little or are so uncertain that I would not rely on one estimator and definitely not only on the estimator you propose.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will search for some good density estimation methods in order to better estimate the CVaR risk.